# c# regular expression equivalent to js regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

Can someone tell me the regular expression equivalent to below javascript expression

```
var validformat = /^[-+]?\d*\.?\d*$/
```

I tried the same in my c# code using below but its failing.

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"/^[-+]?\d*\.?\d*$/")
bool result = rgx.IsMatch(expression)
```

The code is basically to validate the Number - it should allow 20,000 but not 20.3. and 20+3

Comment: Please provide a sample input that it is failing on.

Comment: you regex is failing on 20+3

Comment: this will allow words like : +343.3443

Comment: what do you need, please give sample input and output

Comment: `\d` also matches non-ASCII digits like `०१२۱۲۳` in .NET, do you want to reproduce that behavior in your JavaScript regex?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to get rid of `/` on both sides, as well as changing `\.` to something more specific. If you need more possible separators, just add them inside `[+,]`. You have currently only mentioned `+` and `,` in your question.

Updated the `regex` to remove matching of `20+3`.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System;

public class Program{
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^[-+]?\d*,?\d+$");
        Console.WriteLine(rgx.IsMatch("10000"));  //True
        Console.WriteLine(rgx.IsMatch("20,000")); //True
        Console.WriteLine(rgx.IsMatch("20+100")); // False
        Console.WriteLine(rgx.IsMatch("20000,")); // False
        Console.WriteLine(rgx.IsMatch("20.200")); // False
    }
}
```

Comment: if i remove the "/" from both the sides the code is failing for "20,000" - it should allow this

Comment: @Dipesh your code will fail for most of the things, do you even have a small idea what your regex is doing ?. If you want a regex better update your question'

Comment: I have a javascript regex - which is allowing numeric values and also  check for for format validity. I wanted to use the same to validate @server side - but it didnt worked.

Comment: merlin2011 thanks a lot , small correction it shouldnt be allow 20+3 as a valid input - sorry for the mistake. Please let me know what changes required in that case

Comment: @Dipesh, Just change `[+,]` to `,`. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

better use this regex:

```
^\d*[-+,]?\d*$
```

use it like this in your code :

http://ideone.com/HIgMzp

it will match 20,000 and 20+3 but will not match 20.3 or 100.1

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"^\d*[-+,]?\d*$")
```

Comment: small correction, is it possible to allow 20+3 as a valid input - please let me know what changes are required in that case.

Comment: i dont know what you are seeing, but I must tell you the code i have written above will allow 20+3 as valid input